# iOS : How to implement handwriting recognition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Starting iOS development, I wish to implement handwriting recognition in my app.

I did a google search but i didn't find any tutorial implements text gesture in objective c

Is there any basic tutorial available which implements text gesture...

for example: when user writes `A` on the screen, screen should display `A`

Is there any demo tutorial available for this project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look into [this sample application](https://github.com/ProstetnicSth/Handwriting). In this application first you have to provide the training character and then you app will detect your handwriting.
[image]

Comment: @UPT:Thanx for the Comment, but i am not able to detect my handwriting letter in this project... how you detected ?

Comment: It's very simple, man. Tap on the info icon on lowest corner in application. Then select the character (say u selected A) then it will show the training in below the character. You type A with your hand writing. As soon as you are done, Below A it will say trained. Now when you type the same A (in your handwriting) app will detect that it's A. Same applied to other same characters.

Comment: @UPT: This project is not working in my computer now, initially it was working, but now it is not... i had downloaded again still it is not working..

Comment: when i click on recognize tab i am getting like this...  http://i.imgur.com/4eZ8R.png

Comment: But I can see it's working at my end :). Please go through how to use it. I think you need to understand the app, how to train then how to make writing detectable and then see the debug the match. Tap on icon on the right lower corner and that's it. :)

Comment: @UPT: What are the odds that there is a trained library available for that, or that there is an easy way to train and pull out the data for later packaging?

Answer (score 4):

There are no "text" gesture recognizers.  What you are describing is called handwriting recognition.

The only built-in support for handwriting recognition is in the Chinese "keyboard" settings labeled "handwriting".  There is no API for handwriting recognition.

There do not appear to be any open-source handwriting recognition projects specifically for iOS.

You should just look for a generic open-source handwriting recognition library and port it to iOS.

Comment: +1 for accurate answer, though user being new to iPhone will probably not be capable of doing so :D