# Finger gesture will be translated into word on iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

I want to develop an app which will be similar to the app like this: https://edshelf.com/tool/myscript-calculator. I want to know what kind of APIs are used for developing this app.I want to develop this kind of app for iPad and iPhone.If someone please tell me the procedure for developing this app that will help me a lot.Please help.Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement handwriting recognition in iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108507/how-to-implement-handwriting-recognition-in-ipad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MyScript application on iOS has it's own API to use when developing. Here is a link to the different kinds: [MyScript API List](http://www.visionobjects.com/en/myscript/myscript-application-toolkit/description/)

hope it helps!

Comment: I can't vote up because its not allowing me to vote up.What can i do?